# Django-filter, LinkWidget with Checkbox Select Multiple filter

Tags: django, checkbox, django-filter, multiple-select

I'm trying to create a Checkbox Select Multiple filter with LinkWidget function so that the user doesn't have to submit the form every time the user click on a new check box. Just like Amazon's search: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Digital-Cameras/b/ref=dp_bc_2?ie=UTF8&node=560836

That user can just click on the boxes on the left and render new search directly. 
I'm trying to implement this using [django-filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) package. 
So far I have gotten to the point that by using the LinkWidget widget, I can have LinkWidget filter for one criteria at a time.

```
manufacturer = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
    choices = choice_list,
    widget = django_filters.widgets.LinkWidget
)
```

This allows the user to filter the manufacturers when they click on one of them. However, the filter resets every time the user filters and doesn't add on the filter. 
What I want is a Checkbox Select Multiple filter that has the LinkWidget function.

I tried to use

```
manufacturer = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(
    choices = choice_list,
    widget = django_filters.widgets.LinkWidget
)
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea on how to set this up?